# Hibernate NullPointerException on query.list()?

Tags: java, hibernate

Hi All while I am trying to call DB stored procedure from getNamedQuery statement sometimes NPE is encountered and unable to debug the the code because Db stored proc is executing properly and returning ref cursur.
There seems to be getting resultSet as NULL and while converting ResultSet to List() then it's generating NPE,but not sure :( ?

```
ERROR com.uil.dat.dao.impl.WorkOrderDAOImpl: Exception occurred on calculatePriority DAO method
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader$Metadata.<init>(CustomLoader.java:552)
            at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.autoDiscoverTypes(CustomLoader.java:525)
            at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1878)
            at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:718)
            at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:270)
            at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2449)
            at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2192)
            at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2187)
            at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:316)
            at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1832)
            at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:165)
            at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:179)
            at com.uil.dat.dao.impl.WorkOrderDAOImpl.calculatePriority(WorkOrderDAOImpl.java:60)
            at com.uil.dat.manager.impl.DAOManagerImpl.calculatePriority(DAOManagerImpl.java:154)
            at com.uil.dat.service.spt.impl.WorkOrderServiceImpl.calcPriority(WorkOrderServiceImpl.java:157)
            at com.uil.dat.controller.spt.WorkOrderControllerBean.calcPriority(WorkOrderControllerBean.java:308)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
            at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:268)
            at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278)
            at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:83)
            at javax.faces.component._MethodExpressionToMethodBinding.invoke(_MethodExpressionToMethodBinding.java:88)
            at org.apache.myfaces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:100)
            at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:120)
            at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._broadcastAll(UIViewRoot.java:995)
            at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:278)
            at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._process(UIViewRoot.java:1307)
            at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:733)
            at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationExecutor.execute(InvokeApplicationExecutor.java:34)
            at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:172)
            at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:119)
            at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:189)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1230)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
            at com.uil.dat.filter.RequestFilter.doFilter(RequestFilter.java:74)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:964)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1104)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:914)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
            at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
            at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
            at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
            at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
            at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
            at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
            at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
            at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
            at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
            at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
            at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
            at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1865)
    [12/08/16 06:50:33:033 EDT] Thread:[WebContainer : 5]  WARN org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher: Could not close a JDBC result set
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.closeStatements(AbstractBatcher.java:338)
            at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.cleanup(ConnectionManager.java:405)
            at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.close(ConnectionManager.java:347)
            at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.close(SessionImpl.java:335)
            at com.uil.dat.util.HibernateUtil.close(HibernateUtil.java:54)
            at com.uil.dat.dao.impl.WorkOrderDAOImpl.calculatePriority(WorkOrderDAOImpl.java:94)
            at com.uil.dat.manager.impl.DAOManagerImpl.calculatePriority(DAOManagerImpl.java:154)
            at com.uil.dat.service.spt.impl.WorkOrderServiceImpl.calcPriority(WorkOrderServiceImpl.java:157)
            at com.uil.dat.controller.spt.WorkOrderControllerBean.calcPriority(WorkOrderControllerBean.java:308)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
            at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:268)
            at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278)
            at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:83)
            at javax.faces.component._MethodExpressionToMethodBinding.invoke(_MethodExpressionToMethodBinding.java:88)
            at org.apache.myfaces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:100)
            at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:120)
            at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._broadcastAll(UIViewRoot.java:995)
            at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:278)
            at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._process(UIViewRoot.java:1307)
            at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:733)
            at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationExecutor.execute(InvokeApplicationExecutor.java:34)
            at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:172)
            at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:119)
            at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:189)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1230)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
            at com.uil.dat.filter.RequestFilter.doFilter(RequestFilter.java:74)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:964)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1104)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:914)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
            at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
            at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
            at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
            at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
            at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
            at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
            at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
            at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
            at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
            at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
            at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
            at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
            at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1865)
    [12/08/16 06:50:33:033 EDT] Thread:[WebContainer : 5]  INFO com.uil.dat.
```

Currently I am using Hibernate3.jar along with JSF.

My code for the calling DB stored proc as below :

```
try {
            session = HibernateUtil.buildIfNeeded().openSession();
            if(null!=session && session.isOpen()){
                HibernateUtil.beginTransaction(session);
            }
            logger.info(Constant.INITIATING_DB_CONNECTION);//building session from sessionFactory if not created
            Query query = session.getNamedQuery("callCalculatePriorityProcedure");
            query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(ProcedureReturn.class));
            if(null!= query){
                List<ProcedureReturn> calculatePriority = query.list();
                if(null!= calculatePriority && calculatePriority.size()>0){
                    for(ProcedureReturn procedureReturn:calculatePriority){
                        if(Integer.parseInt(procedureReturn.getRETURNINTEGER())==0){
                            result = 0;
                            logger.info("procedure has bene executed successfully");
                        }
                        else{
                            result = 1;
                            logger.info("procedure wasn't executed successfully");
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    result = 2;
                }   
            }
```

Comment: That might depend on the query and the mapping of the entities you try to load. Oh and while you're at it, can you tell us the exact Hibernate version you're using? There's something null in the initialization block of `CustomLoader$Metadata` so you could try and have a look at the sources to see what's null there.

Comment: @Thomas query used for calling stored proc is : <sql-query name="callCalculatePriorityProcedure" callable="true">
       <![CDATA[CALL PKG_DA_OMS_SPT.CALC_PRIORITY(?)]]>
     </sql-query>

Comment: Wouldn't you have to pass a parameter to the query? I don't see you do that.

Comment: and hibernate version is : hibernate-3 
and jars we are using is :

Comment: @Thomas we are not passing any input parameter and only getting ref cursor returned from the stored proc as output parameter which is passed as single ? in procedure call

Answer (score 0):

Now,As I found the root cause of issue and it was nothing that could be resolved from java hibernate side. We we're using DB links to fetch the data from view ,due to some glitch DB link sometimes failed to fetch any record and keeps going to exception part and returns nothing. Now we needed to handle DB exception in DB procedure itself so that it returns some value even when exception occurrs , So that it could be identified that DB link went down for some reason.
BTW, Thanks @Thomas.